# How do I fix an uninitialized constant error in Sidekiq 5.0.4?

Tags: sidekiq

A particular Sidekiq job (one of three) is failing with:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant VerifiedReplacementRequestWorker
```

A stack backtrace in NewRelic reports:

```
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 237:in `block in constantize'
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 236:in `each'
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 236:in `inject'
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 236:in `constantize'
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 137:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
…/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq.rb:  36:in `call'
…/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq.rb:  36:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>'
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 136:in `call'
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 136:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
…ruby-2.2.4/gems/sidekiq-5.0.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 215:in `stats'
```

Looking at the source, this correlates with this code:

```
@reloader.call do
  klass  = constantize(job_hash['class'.freeze])
  worker = klass.new
  worker.jid = job_hash['jid'.freeze]
  @retrier.local(worker, job_hash, queue) do
    yield worker
   end
end
```

And the bulk of the reloading is done by this..

```
def constantize(str)
  names = str.split('::')
  names.shift if names.empty? || names.first.empty?

  names.inject(Object) do |constant, name|
    constant.const_defined?(name) ? constant.const_get(name) : constant.const_missing(name)
  end
end
```

The question is: Why can't it find the code?

I have tried manually requiring the Sidekiq job classes from a Rails initializer and even from the code that queues the job. Nothing seems to find this particular class, although there are two other job classes that do not seem to experience this loading issue.

Where does the `constantize` method look for code?

This fails in staging, but does not seem to fail in the production environment. Development inlines the Sidekiq jobs, so that does not demonstrate the problem either.

Looking for some clues how to solve this.

The code for the worker class in question lives in Rails in *app/workers*. I have tried modifying Rails' autoload and eager load paths to no avail.